# "No Internet Connection" when installing apps in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio 3.1, and I've spun up a Nexus 5x AVD that has the Google Play service installed.

The AVD can access the Internet fine, it can check emails, it can browse, it can install updates - but it can't install apps. Every time I try to install an app I get an error message saying "No Internet connection..."

What can I do to fix this?[image]

Comment: make sure you have set the internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @AmirDe I'm not trying to run an app - just install something via Google Play store

Answer (score 0):

You might have your proxy configuration in the emulator enabled by mistake.

1. Go to the emulator
2. 3 dots on bottom of the menu
3. Settings
4. proxy
5. uncheck "use android studio http proxy settings"
6. select no proxy
7. click apply

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I came across this: It seems like Google Play when run on an emulator will always display this and not allow any installs. The theory was they don't want one person to be able to make multiple reviews about an app. I am open to be corrected on this.